# Is it possible to apply dbt seed configurations to all projects that use a given package?

Tags: dbt

I built a dbt package for internal use. I'd like to specify the seed configurations in the `dbt_project.yml` of that package, and have those configurations apply to all projects that use the package. So far, I'm not sure if there's an issue with my syntax or if this just isn't possible.

The package `dbt_project.yml` includes the following:

```
seeds:
  seed_name:
    +quote_columns: false
    +column_types:
          column_name: varchar(127)
```

In a project that uses this package, there is a file `data/seed_name.csv`. When I run `dbt seed` for that project, I want the configuration defined in the package to apply to this seed. Instead, it seems to be ignored. To be clear, the .csv is included in the project that uses the package, not in the package itself.

It works if I move the above code out of the package and into the project-specific `dbt_project.yml`. However, this would mean that anyone using my package needs to copy that code into their file, which I'd prefer to avoid.

Comment: Why do you need to keep the column configurations in the `dbt_project.yml`? I'd try experimenting with a new seed properties yml and just trying to specify the column types there: [Seed Properties](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/seed-properties)

So instead you'd have a new `data/seed_name.yml` with the `seeds:` param tree with column types defined there. At least give that a shot.

Comment: Unfortunately I specifically need to set the column lengths, and I don't see a way to include that as a property? The specific problem that occurs is that, e.g. if a package user runs `dbt seed` when their column has a maximum length of 25, the data will be loaded as type varchar(25). If they then add a longer string to that column, the following `dbt seed` fails.

Essentially, I'd like to have control over the column length (127 in this case) as the package owner, even though package users will be uploading their own seed data.

Comment: I should also add that I know that `--full-refresh` would help with this particular problem, but there are other things that I'd like to configure at the package level as well.

Comment: No, I dont think it has anything to do with the refresh. I want to say it is either how you have your package dbt_project.yml defined with [resource paths](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/resource-path) which aren't being found on import of that package to your main project.

Comment: Side note - you are running `dbt clean` / `dbt deps` after marking changes to your package definition right? I made that mistake (making changes and then not re-installing the package to the test project) at least once when I was in a tight build cycle on my package.

Comment: I just meant that `--full-refresh` would solve the column length problem, not the broader seed config issue. I'll take another look at the resource paths docs, but I had hoped that excluding resource paths entirely would have allowed everything in the package to apply to the projects. I ended up submitting a feature request, but I'll share the answer here if it turns out I was just doing it wrong. Thanks for the replies!